# Is there an algebraic formula for the eigenvalues of a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix?

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, galois-theory

Is there a formula in radicals for the eigenvalues, or at least the largest eigenvalue, of an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, in terms of the entries?  For what $n$ is there a formula?  There obviously is if $n\leq 4$, and one suspects not if $n\geq 5$.  However, the characteristic polynomial of a symmetric matrix is rather special (e.g. all roots are real) and could possibly be solvable by radicals for larger $n$, although I would guess not.

Comment: Have you tried computing the Galois group of a random example?

Comment: Edward Bender, Characteristic ppolynomials of symmetric matrices, proved that any totally real monic polynomial of odd degree with rational coefficients can occur as the characteristic polynomial of a symmetric rational matrix. Some discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574443/which-polynomials-are-characteristic-polynomials-of-a-symmetric-matrix

Comment: Here us a formula literally "in radicals" for the largest eigenvalue, although probably not what you had in mind: $$ \lambda_1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\|A^n\|}.$$ (Of course, if you want a purely algebraic expression, there is no way to distinguish the largest eigenvalue from the others.)

Comment: About Gerry's comment. Given a totally real monic polynomial $P$ of degree $n$, a simple procedure constructs a "companion" in the form of a real symmetric tridiagonal matrix $T$. If $P$ has rational coefficients (or in a number field $k$), then $T$ has rational entries (resp. in $k$). See Exercise #92 in my list http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/serre/DPF/exobis.pdf .

Comment: If one takes your question more broadly as a sign that you need to know more about maps (class of numbers to take the entries of the matrix from)$\rightarrow$(class of all numbers that arise as ev of symmetric matrices), then the following might help: for any finite symmetric matrix, if all entries come from a fixed _real-closed_ field $K$, then then all eigenvalues of the matrix are still in $K$.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I calculated correctly, $$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\newline 1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0\newline 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \newline 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \newline 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ has characteristic polynomial $-x^5+8x^4-20x^3+15x^2+4x-5$ which is irreducible mod $3$ and has $3$ linear factors and a quadratic factor mod $79$, so its Galois group is $S_5$, so its roots can't be expressed with just radicals.

Comment: [Sage Math agrees with you](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFzUEKwjAUBNC94B1CVwmEUHVrXbr0AiGUbxrix8SE3xSsp7e2amE282AYYA2LUAifXOu9ZDvJ6iVGMj21w98-UM9tyQ9WW-Frxojt5q6Or9N0cxni1dEZXeg4KHsDAlscYV_QtjmF8ZEiQuBi3ngICfvWUxoyL2N2TeUhV0Il6hxx8QYbXzIi&lang=sage).